# Ajax - Render JSon to HTML : View vs Controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to append the results of an Ajax request to a table I have on my page. I see 2 ways of rendering the rows :

- my Controller could return a JSon array that I will then decode in the view and create a Javascript function to properly add the adequate HTML markup
- my Controller could directly return the HTML

What is the best practice on that matter?

Comment: do you want it reusable by processes that will not convert the output to html?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use that ways

- Send ajax to PHP file with `dataType: 'json'`
- At `PHP`: I processing data and json_encode the data array and die it to return result to HTML
- on Success function of Ajax, i process the data